# Extract all characters minus a certain set of characters from a substring

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I happened to be looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60440876/9494044) question, and I chanced upon this string:

```
#2335, IFCRELASSOCIATESMATERIAL, '2ON6$yXXD1GAAH8whbdZmc', #5,$,$, [#40,#221,#268,#281],#2334
```

And I got interested in trying to replace only the commas (`,`) within the substring `[#40,#221,#268,#281]` with underscores (`_`). I was attempting this in `R` with the `stringr` package, and my idea was to use `str_replace()` as follows:

- First locate the substring in the parent string with lookarounds: `(?<=\\[).+(?=\\[)`. (I am using `\\` to escape since that's what `stringr` uses.)
- Then match all instances of only the commas within the substring with `[^0-9#]+`. So now the regex would be `(?<=\\[)[^0-9#]+(?=\\[)`.
- Now use `str_replace()` to replace the above matches with `_` as follows: `str_replace(mystring, "(?<=\\[)[^0-9#]+(?=\\[)", "_")`
- where `mystring` contains the string `#2335, IFCRELASSOCIATESMATERIAL, '2ON6$yXXD1GAAH8whbdZmc', #5,$,$, [#40,#221,#268,#281],#2334`

I thought the regex I constructed should parse as: *replace one or more characters that are not `digits` or `#` within the bounds of `[` and `]` with the character `_`*. But evidently, this isn't the case as my attempt did not work.

Where am I going wrong and what is/are the right way(s) to solve regex problems of this kind?

**tl;dr:** how does one extract all tokens but a certain token (or set of tokens) from a substring bounded by two other arbitrary tokens?

Comment: `str_replace_all(string, "\\[[^\\]\\[]+]", function(x) gsub(",", "_", x, fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: I always forget that functions can be passed as arguments. The `gsub()` solution is neat, and it works with the lookarounds too!!

Comment: Or if you are a bit more adventurous, using the Continue operator `\G` and smart use of `\K`: `(?:\[#\d+\K,|(?<!^)\G,)(#\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/ZQpgGa/1